# I can't seem to combine 2 tables in MySQL using LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that I need results from in one overview.
This is al done using MySQL 5.5.44

Table 1

| id(PK) | medewerker(VARCHAR) | klantnummer(INT) | datum(DATE) | tijd(TIME) | actief(TINYINT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | 12345 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | 12345 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |
| 3 | John Doe | 12345 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |
| 4 | John Doe | 12345 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |

Table 2

| id(PK) | medewerker(VARCHAR) | reden(VARCHAR) | waarde(INT) | datum(DATE) | tijd(TIME) | actief(TINYINT) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe | Error | -33 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |
| 2 | Jane Doe | Vacation | 110 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |
| 3 | John Doe | Test | 10 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |
| 4 | John Doe | Check | 40 | 1-1-2020 | 10:00:01 | 1 |

Now I want to count how many times each employee is visible in Table 1 so normally I do this.

```
SELECT `medewerker` `Employee`,count(`medewerker`) `Total` FROM bb.aa group by `medewerker`
```

| Employee | Total |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | 3 |
| Jane Doe | 1 |

And I also need the sum of 'waarde' from table 2.

```
SELECT `medewerker` `Employee`,sum(waarde) `ExtraValue` FROM bb.bb GROUP BY `medewerker`
```

| Employee | ExtraValue |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | 17 |
| Jane Doe | 110 |

These 2 tables need to come together and become one. There is also a chance that an employee does exist in table 1 but not in table 2 and vice versa.
Nut sure if that will cause problems. But I am not sure on how to do this, I can't seem to understand how I need to use LEFT JOIN in this.

Just to be clear this is what I want.

| Employee | Total | ExtraValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | 3 | 17 |
| John Doe | 1 | 110 |

I tried to do something like this based on stuff I found on the internet but this isn't working and giving a time-out because I tried it on live data. And took longer than 30 seconds to generate it.

```
SELECT aa.medewerker, count(aa.medewerker),sum(bb.waarde) 
FROM aa.aa  LEFT JOIN aa.bb 
ON bb.medewerker = aa.medewerker 
group by aa.medewerker
```

---

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aa`.`bb` (
  `idBonusVermindering` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `medewerker` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `reden` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  `datum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `tijd` TIME NOT NULL,
  `waarde` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBonusVermindering`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idBonusVermindering_UNIQUE` (`idBonusVermindering` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 646
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `aa`.`aa` (
  `medewerker` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `klantnummer` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `datum` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Actief` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `tijd` TIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 210502
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: MySQL 5.5.44 is the version I am running

Comment: having a group by on a person's name is not a good idea.  That should be a primary table of names so you have a proper PK / FK.  In America, if you had a name like "John Smith", you might have 100 different instances and thus bad count results.  See if you can update your database normalization to account for it if not now, sometime soon before this becomes a bigger problem.

Comment: @DRapp thank you for your answer, these things were never intended to be used like this. This old code with even worse databases. I just needed to this work for maybe a few more months till we get the new system rolled out. The new system uses user_id's everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `FULL` outer join for your queries, which is not supported by MySql and can only be simulated by `UNION ALL` of 2 separate queries:

```
SELECT q1.Employee, q1.Total, COALESCE(q2.ExtraValue, 0) ExtraValue 
FROM (SELECT medewerker Employee, COUNT(*) Total FROM aa GROUP BY Employee) q1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT medewerker Employee, SUM(waarde) ExtraValue FROM bb GROUP BY medewerker) q2 
ON q1.Employee = q2.Employee
UNION ALL
SELECT q2.Employee, COALESCE(q1.Total, 0) Total, q2.ExtraValue 
FROM (SELECT medewerker Employee, COUNT(*) Total FROM aa GROUP BY Employee) q1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT medewerker Employee, SUM(waarde) ExtraValue FROM bb GROUP BY medewerker) q2 
ON q1.Employee = q2.Employee
WHERE q1.Employee IS NULL
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6245faafb3ac469f6871bdbcb9ea5731).
Results:

```
> Employee | Total | ExtraValue
> :------- | ----: | ---------:
> Jane Doe |     1 |        110
> John Doe |     3 |         17
```

Comment: This is it, so my problem was that I needed a full join. Which isn't supported by MySQL.
Thank you for your help! I was trying way to long to solve this ahahahah

Comment: @JeffreyLionelvanHoudt also your version of MySQL which is quite old. In the latest version 8.0+ the query could be written with the use of CTEs and it could be less verbose and more efficient.

Comment: This is an old server with some old legacy code we just don't want to touch, we just need it to run for a few months till we get the new system in place. New system runs using MySQL 8.0 and finally C# with .net 5 instead of vb.net with framework 3.5